# Compare and replace value with another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following arrays:

```
$files = ['376840000000367020', '376840000000375036', '376840000000389001'];
$arr   = [];

foreach ($files as $key => $name) {
    $arr[] = $name;
}

$data = [
    '376840000000367020' => '5782',
    '376840000000375036' => '5783',
    '376840000000389001' => '5784',
];

print_r($arr);
```

This returns:

```
Array ( [0] => 376840000000367020 [1] => 376840000000375036.... )
```

I want to compare 2 arrays `$arr` and `$data` if the `$key` is found in `$arr` replace value with the `$data`, I'm trying get following output:

```
Array ( [0] => 5782 [1] => 5783 .... )
```

I have lots of data to compare so its not ideal to iterate over `$arr` inside foreach.

How would i go about doing this?

Comment: iterate over all entries in $arr, check if the current entry exists within $data if yes replace, otherwise go on

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: $arr should search in $data if there is a match $arr should replace value with $data i'e 5782,5783 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) function to check a **key** exists in array:

```
<?php

$files = ['376840000000367020','376840000000375036','376840000000389001'];

$data = array(
    '376840000000367020'  =>  '5782',
    '376840000000375036'  =>  '5783',
    '376840000000389001'  =>  '5784',
);

$arr = [];
foreach($files as $key=>$name){
    if(array_key_exists($name, $data)) {
        $arr[] = $data[$name];
    }
}


print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate `$files` array and check if value is in `$data`

```
foreach ($files as &$file) {
   if (isset($data[$file])) {
       $file = $data[$file];
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but it does not give me any output, just blank screen

Comment: Do you do `var_dump($files);`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) passing a callback that checks if the value exist in the 2nd array and return it's value in that case, or the item otherwise.

Comment: try the given example in the doc. If u have trouble understanding it, explain your doubts and i ll be happy to help